# Let the user specify a file name in C

Tags: c, string, file

This is my code:

```
char filename[30];
FILE *fp;
printf(" Enter the filename: ");
gets(filename);
strcat(filename,".txt");
fp=fopen("e:\\filename","a+");
```

**So my problem is that I want the user to specify a file name then open that file and write on it. But every time I am running this code it opens a file named: filename instead of opening the value which is present on the string filename[30].**

Comment: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) Instead, `fgets (filename, sizeof filename, stdin);`

Answer (score 3):

You are *"Tap Dancing on a Landmine"* and flirting with *Undefined Behavior* by concatenating text without checking if there are sufficient character available in `filename` before calling `strcat`. What if the user enters a 26-character `filename` (or more)? (hint: undefined behavior)

This is compounded by the fact you are using `gets` for input. `gets` is so insecure and so prone to exploit by buffer overrun it has been completely removed in C11. If your professor is suggesting the use of `gets` -- go get another professor. See: [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Instead use `fgets` or POSIX `getline` to read the `filename` while protecting your arrays bounds with `fgets` or dynamically allocating as much storage as needed for `filename` in the case of `getline`.

All *line-oriented input* functions like `fgets` and `getline` read and ***include*** the trailing `'\n'` in the buffers they fill. You simply need to trim the `'\n'` from the end of the string. You can do so by getting the length with `strlen` and setting `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';` or by using the  `strcspn` function which provides a bit more functionality in one call.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following (that just outputs the `fopen` call rather than actually opening the file):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 30         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define FEXT ".txt"     /* (including string constants) */

int main (void) {

    char filename[MAXC];
    size_t  available = MAXC - 1,   /* chars available in filename */
            length = 0,
            extlen = strlen (FEXT);
    FILE *fp;

    fputs (" Enter the filename: ", stdout);    /* no conversion needed */
    if (!fgets (filename, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* trim '\n' from end of filename saving length using strcspn() */
    filename[(length = strcspn (filename, "\r\n"))] = 0;

    if (available - length < extlen) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient space available for '%s'.\n", 
                FEXT);
        return 1;
    }

    strcat (filename, FEXT);
    /* just output what would be done */
    printf ("fp = fopen (\"e:\\%s\",\"a+\");\n", filename);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The example simply prints what it would open (rather than actuall opening the file), e.g.

```
$ ./bin/strcatext
 Enter the filename: my_file_to_open
fp = fopen ("e:\my_file_to_open.txt","a+");
```

And then check that your code will accept a 25-character filename plus 4-character extension, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/strcatext
 Enter the filename: 1234567890123456789012345
fp = fopen ("e:\1234567890123456789012345.txt","a+");
```

And rejects a 26-character filename, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/strcatext
 Enter the filename: 12345678901234567890123456
error: insufficient space available for '.txt'.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Hopefully this will help with the character accounting. The last big piece of advice -- *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!* (so go back and change `#define MAXC 30` to at least `#define MAXC 512` (or if you are on Linux, `#include <limits.h>` and use `char filename[PATH_MAX];` (which is `2048`). That way you are less likely to run out of room in `filename`. (I think windows had a `256` char limit on filenames, but I believe it is going to at least `512`)